# How to use arrays in loop with if statment in django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to choose include button_free when hour_1 is 0 or choose button_busy when hour_0 is 1

**view**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['hour_1'] = [0,0,1,1,0]
    context['range_5'] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    return context
```

`
**part of template**

```
{% for schedule_part in range_5 %}
    {% if hour_1.schedule_part == 0 %}
        {% include  "users/button_free.html" with button_id=hour_1.schedule_part %}
    {% else %}
        {% include  "users/button_busy.html" with button_id=hour_1.schedule_part %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

hour_1 is for example [0,0,1,1,0]

Displays only button_busy

When debugging hour_1.schedule_par raises VariableDoesNotExist exception.
How should I get to the hour_1 elements

Comment: context[hour_1] = [0,0,1,1,0] should be changed to context['hour_1'] = [0,0,1,1,0] because  you pass  hour_1 directly it should change to string format 'hour_1'

Comment: it really looks like this
hour = ['hour_1', 'hour_2', 'hour_3', 'hour_4', 'hour_5', 'hour_6', 'hour_7']
        for hour_i, i in zip(hour, range(0, len(user_schedule), 5)):
            context[hour_i] = user_schedule[i:i+5]
A small mistake in simplification. I edited post

Comment: you should used list indexing in code 
{% for schedule_part in range_5 %}
    {% if hour_1[schedule_part] == 0 %}
        {% include  "users/button_free.html" with button_id=hour_1[schedule_part] %}
    {% else %}
        {% include  "users/button_busy.html" with button_id=hour_1[schedule_part]%}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: Just for sake of clarity, in Python, and "array" is referred to as a "list".

Comment: @AhmedSalman I replied in your answer.  Did not work